# I would like to pass an Image tag data to servlet. How?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page where am displaying image (which is generated in servlet and passed with name in jsp) and accepting text. Now i would like to pass that image tag value and textarea value to another jsp page. I am able to get textarea value but how to retrieve image to servlet.

**JSP code**:

```
<form id="form1" action="CallServlet">
<img src="PieChartDemo" width="600" height="400" border="0" name="chartsample"/><br>
<textarea rows="4" cols="150" id=t1 name=t1></textarea>
<input type="Submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

**Servlet Code**:

```
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
PieChartDemo pcd=new PieChartDemo();
String textvalues=request.getParameter("t1");
System.out.println("Text values : "+textvalues);
out.println(textvalues);
```

Now i would like to display or store it into a variable that image. How to go about? Suggest.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You want the actual binary content of the image? Why not set some values on the session and read them in the other JSP?

Comment: Hi Sotirios, Thank you for response. But could you please suggest how to store that value, because am calling a chart here which is calculated in servlet1(calculation)--> jsp(image,textarea)-->servlet2. Here jsp is showing that chart which is calculated in servlet1, remaining flow i have specified in code

Comment: Who are you asking what? I asked: Do you need the actual binary image data?

Comment: Hi sir, Yes i require actual binary image data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata

Comment: Thank you this was helpful when i would like to store it in blob and extract it.

Answer (score 1):

you can not upload files using `getParameter` method. 
for that u will have to use `apache file upload`.

Just go through the following link it will definatley solve your problem.

[servlets-file-uploading](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm)